# hiding a div with css #id based on another div #id having a particular css class assigned to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, variables

I'm a bit of a jscript novice and im working with a html template that already has some js in it.
essentially my question is this....

the class of the `div#header-container` changes dependent on where you are scrolled on the screen. 
if div#header-container CLASS is not equal to .intro. then I need to hide another div on the page which has ID `#intro`.

the `#header-container` class is `.intro` at the start and then when you scroll below the (`div#intro`) at the beginning, the `#header-container` class changes from `.intro` to `.main` - thats when i need to hide the pre-existing `div#intro`.

in essence i'm looking to recreate what http://www.mountaindew.com have done when you scroll past the first screen

I'm guessing I need to use `document.getElementByClassName` somewhere?

any ideas massively appreciated!

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind window object with scroll and check **`header-container`** have class **`intro`**.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('#header-container').hasClass('intro')) {
     $('#intro').show();
  } else {
     $('#intro').hide();
  } 
});
```

Comment: hmm that seems to make perfect sense. it's not working though...does this call the function every time the body is scrolled down or just the first time - $('body').scroll(function()

no idea why this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery

like the following code inside the scroll event.

```
if(jQuery("#header-container").hasClass('intro')){
  jQuery("#intro").hide();
  jQuery("#header-container").removeClass('intro');
  jQuery("#header-container").addClass('main');

}
```

something like this ???